# How to display only a number with out the date in php - codeigniter?

Tags: php

I'm trying to print something in my page. I have an array of having dates as well as numbers. As I use for loops, the numbers printed as well as the date.  I want only to display the number. How can I do that? I even use type casting, but still no good. Please help.

by the way here's the code...

```
    $date = $this->controllerModel->processData($this->input->post('textarea'));
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($date); $i++){
        echo "array[".$i."] = " . $date[$i];
        echo "<br /><br />";
    }
    $tempVar = array(array());
    $k = 0;

    for($i = 1; $i < 250; $i++){
        for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($date); $j++){
            if($i == $date[$j]){
                $tempVar[$i][$k] = $date[$j];
            }
        }
    }
    for($i = 1; $i < 250; $i++){
        for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($date); $j++){
            if(empty($tempVar[$i][$j])){
                 echo ".";
            } 
            else  echo $tempVar[$i][$j];
        }
    }
}
```

in my model...

```
public function processData($textarea){
    $data = explode("_", $textarea);
    return $data;
}
```

the textarea is the input box.

edit: the input...

```
36  _   Arnel Lent  _   2/14/2014 0:33
36  _   Arnel Lent  _   2/14/2014 4:35
21  _   Roche Ingk  _   2/14/2014 7:48
199 _   Emmanuel Muring _   2/14/2014 7:50
199 _   Emmanuel Muring _   2/14/2014 7:50
```

Comment: can you give sample value/input for the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already solved...

I just make a date function and some if statements.

And after that I use an array to eliminate same numbers.